# how to remove html tags from json?

Tags: android, json

```
[{"id":1,"header":"<tr><td style=\"width:5.36%\" width=\"5%\" valign=\"top\"></td><td style=\"width:94.48%\" width=\"94%\" colspan=\"2\" valign=\"top\">  <p style=\"margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt\"><span style='font-family:\"Cambria Math\",serif'>The unit of Wien&#8217;s constant </span><span style='font-size:11.0ptline-height:115%font-family:\"Calibri\",sans-serifposition:relativetop:4.5pt'><img width=\"8\" height=\"20\" src=\"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAgAAAAUAQMAAACK1e4oAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAAZQTFRFAAAAAAAApWe5zwAAAAF0Uk5TAEDm2GYAAAAJcEhZcwAADsQAAA7EAZUrDhsAAAAZdEVYdFNvZnR3YXJlAE1pY3Jvc29mdCBPZmZpY2V/7TVxAAAAH0lEQVQYV2NgAAMDBgEg1GMwYlACQjcGF4YKiAQMAAAqagH3u8+wVwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==\"></span><span style='font-family:\"Cambria Math\",serif'>&nbsp;is </span></p>  </td><td style width=\"0%\" colspan=\"2\"><p>&nbsp;</p></td></tr>","qOptions":"[{\"OptionNo\":\"a\",\"ValueHtml\":\"<tr><td style=\\\"width:5.36%\\\" width=\\\"5%\\\" valign=\\\"top\\\">  <p><span style='font-family:\\\"Cambria\\\",serif'>&nbsp;</span></p>  </td><td style=\\\"width:2.4%\\\" width=\\\"2%\\\">  <p><span style='font-family:\\\"Cambria\\\",serif'>a)</span></p>  </td><td style=\\\"width:92.14%\\\" width=\\\"92%\\\" colspan=\\\"2\\\">  <p style=\\\"margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt\\\"><span style='font-size:11.0ptline-height:115%font-family:\\\"Calibri\\\",sans-serif'><img width=\\\"65\\\" height=\\\"20\\\" src=\\\"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAEEAAAAUAQMAAADoesJCAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAAZQTFRFAAAAAAAApWe5zwAAAAF0Uk5TAEDm2GYAAAAJcEhZcwAADsQAAA7EAZUrDhsAAAAZdEVYdFNvZnR3YXJlAE1pY3Jvc29mdCBPZmZpY2V/7TVxAAAAaUlEQVQYV2NgwAH4GBiYIFJCDAxsDAyPLIAClge4GBicBBjkWwT6TzUwuAowMHAIMsgDWYKbGQSEQDpUFc40yIkwMDMwaCzoaGCQAZkAZgGNgbIEQSwBB6CYQAOI5Xj3AIPlAVwOIU4cAGqKE6T9p+R5AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC\\\"></span></p>  </td><td style width=\\\"0%\\\"><p>&nbsp;</p></td></tr>\"},{\"OptionNo\":\"b\",\"ValueHtml\":\"<tr><td style=\\\"width:5.36%\\\" width=\\\"5%\\\" valign=\\\"top\\\">  <p><span style='font-family:\\\"Cambria\\\",serif'>&nbsp;</span></p>  </td><td style=\\\"width:2.4%\\\" width=\\\"2%\\\">  <p><span style='font-family:\\\"Cambria\\\",serif'>b)</span></p>  </td><td style=\\\"width:92.14%\\\" width=\\\"92%\\\" colspan=\\\"2\\\">  <p style=\\\"margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt\\\"><span style='font-size:11.0ptline-height:115%font-family:\\\"Calibri\\\",sans-serif'><img width=\\\"51\\\" height=\\\"20\\\" src=\\\"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADMAAAAUAQMAAAAaxpfnAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAAZQTFRFAAAAAAAApWe5zwAAAAF0Uk5TAEDm2GYAAAAJcEhZcwAADsQAAA7EAZUrDhsAAAAZdEVYdFNvZnR3YXJlAE1pY3Jvc29mdCBPZmZpY2V/7TVxAAAAS0lEQVQYV2NgwACMQJEGIGZnYGAG0Yx8BSA++0MW5Q9gPosDkJ9zgJGlAUgbK7AfZWB+wKCkANLAAKKB4hDaAUorAOnyAgagOSQDAOKkDOJJ7pIYAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC\\\"></span></p>  </td><td style width=\\\"0%\\\"><p>&nbsp;</p></td></tr>\"},{\"OptionNo\":\"c\",\"ValueHtml\":\"<tr><td style=\\\"width:5.36%\\\" width=\\\"5%\\\" valign=\\\"top\\\">  <p><span style='font-family:\\\"Cambria\\\",serif'>&nbsp;</span></p>  </td><td style=\\\"width:2.4%\\\" width=\\\"2%\\\">  <p><span style='font-family:\\\"Cambria\\\",serif'>c)</span></p>  </td><td style=\\\"width:92.14%\\\" width=\\\"92%\\\" colspan=\\\"2\\\">  <p style=\\\"margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt\\\"><span style='font-size:11.0ptline-height:115%font-family:\\\"Calibri\\\",sans-serif'><img width=\\\"32\\\" height=\\\"20\\\"
```

I'm new to android and I'm retrieving data from the above json and displaying it in a list. Everything works fine but if I retrieved the data it shows the html tag also. Please clarify my doubt how to remove html tags from the json, while showing it in a list view.

Comment: first post your full json response

Comment: This json is invalid

Comment: Ask your JSON provider i.e. backend programmer to send data in plain json and not include html tags.

Comment: Thanks Rohit can you please tell me how you are saying it as invalid. or is it not possible to remove HTML tags

Comment: Thanks devutkarsh. it has some equations so my backend developer said that he can pass it only with tags

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression to remove them -

```
var myString = '[{"id":1,"header":"<tr><td style=\"width:5.36%\" width=\"5%\">Test</td>"}]';
var newString = myString.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '');
```

A complete example to your code is as -

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#test").click(function(){
        $.get("http://qbankapi.exambash.com/api/exam/GetAllTestquestions?testid=1", function(data, status){
            var str = JSON.stringify(data);
            alert(str); // json from URL
            var newString = str.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '');
            alert(newString); // string with replaced HTML tags
            var newStr = JSON.parse(newString); // new JSON to use
            console.log(newStr);
        });
    });
});
</script>
<script>

</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="test" >Click</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: dude am getting datas from json how can i set it as  a string. i have tried this method but its not working

Comment: if u need i can send my json link also

Comment: Use JSON.stringify() to convert json to Stirng. Then replace the HTML and then do a JSON.parse() to convert back to JSON and use it.

Comment: Sure, share it. Add it to your question.

Comment: I will take a look and let you know. Accept the answer of it helps.

Comment: Sure i will be waiting for your reply

Comment: I updated my answer. Please find the solution, you can use the similar code in android application.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
myHtmlString.replaceAll("s/<(.*?)>//g","");
Html.fromHtml(htmlSrc).toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

its a bad approach ...you have to validate json response by json validate.

try to change response from backend ...
even you can replace [",;,/...etc] by replace string with null in java...

- html = html.replaceAll("<(.*?)\>"," ");//Removes all items in
  brackets
        html = html.replaceAll("<(.*?)\\n"," ");//Must be undeneath
        html = html.replaceFirst("(.*?)\>", " ");//Removes any connected item to the last bracket
        html = html.replaceAll(" "," ");
        html = html.replaceAll("&"," ");